# Fortran: How to skip many lines of data file efficiently

Tags: file-io, fortran

I have a formatted data file which is typically billions of lines long, with several lines of headers of variable length. The data file takes the form:

```
    # header 1
    # header 2
    # headers are of variable length.
    # data begins from next line.
    1.23  4.56  7.89  0.12
    2.34  5.67  8.90  1.23
    :
    :
    # billions of lines of data, each row the same length, same format.
    -- end of file --
```

I would like to extract a portion of data from this file, and my current code looks like:

```
<pre>
do j=1,jmax !Suppose I want to extract jmax lines of data from the file.

  [algorithm to determine number of lines to skip, "N(j)"]
  !This determines the number of lines to skip from the previous file
  !position, when the data was read on j-1th iteration.

  !Skip N-1 lines to go to the next data line to read off:
  do i=1,N-1
    read(unit=unit,fmt='(A)')
  end do
  !Now read off the line of data I want:
  read(unit=unit,fmt='(data_format)'),data1,data2,etc.
  !Data is stored in some arrays.
end do
</pre>
```

The problem is, N(j) can be anywhere between 1 and several billion, so it takes some time to run the code.

My question is, is there a more efficient way of skipping millions of lines of data? The only way I can think of, while sticking to Fortran, is to open the file with direct access and jump to the desired line upon opening the file.

Comment: You can also open as stream, read the header and then calculate the position of the beginning of your line.

Comment: What has written the file?  What conventions need to be handled in terms of record delimiters/line feed characters?  Can the file be treated as an unformatted stream of character data with ACHAR(10) for line endings?

Comment: The file is an output from another of my code. The numbers are integers and double precisionrs, and they were written into the file with something like: "write(unit=unit,fmt='(I5,I4,ES12.4,ES16.8)'))", looped over as many times as there are pieces of data.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, direct access seems like the best option.  But that requires the records to all have the same length, which your headers violate.  Also, why used formatted output?  With a file of this length, its hard to imagine a person reading the file.  If you use unformatted IO, the file will be both smaller and IO will be faster.  Perhaps create two files, one with the headers (metadata) in human reader form, and the other with the data in native form.  Native / binary representation means a loss of portability, which is something to consider if you want to move the files to different computer architectures or have them be useable for decades.  Otherwise it's probably worth the convenience.  Other options would be to use a more sophisticated file format that combines metadata and data, such as HDF5 or FITS, but for communication between two programs of one person, that's probably excessive.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. That the file is formatted is a bit of legacy from the time when I was first developing my main code and the output data was much much smaller. So now is probably the time to consider changing it to binary output.